# How to set hanging indent of a description list

Tags: beamer, description

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Postopki sodostopa do prenosnega medija}
%------------------------------------------------------------  78
    \begin{description}
\item[Dostop v dodeljeni časovni reži (TDMA):]
    vsakemu uporabniku omrežja -- nadalje bomo zanj uporabljali termin \alert{postaja} -- je dodeljena časovna reža, v kateri lahko pošilja svoje podatke.
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Question: How to reduce the hanging indent?

Comment: To to clarify the question: Do you want to change the position of "Dostop..." or of the following lines "omrezja...."? (sorry, I don't know how to type the special z letter :)

Comment: @samcarter, firs line of list is ok. `\leftmargini` (is this correct name?), i.e. left borders of second and all following lines are to far to the right. your answer solve my problem.

Comment: `\leftmargini` normally sets the space between the left boarder and the start of the item, that confused me a bit :)

Comment: I tried to clarify the question a bit, please feel free to roll-back my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not yet entierly sure which margin you want to modify, but in case you want to change the width of the hanging indent:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\beamer@descriptionwidth=0.5cm
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Postopki sodostopa do prenosnega medija}
%------------------------------------------------------------  78
    \begin{description}
\item[Dostop v dodeljeni časovni reži (TDMA):]
    vsakemu uporabniku omrežja -- nadalje bomo zanj uporabljali termin \alert{postaja} -- je dodeljena časovna reža, v kateri lahko pošilja svoje podatke.
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this works! thank you very much. for accepting i will wait for while ...